# Conditional TabStyle

Tags: visualforce

I have one VF page that I'd like to use for multiple tabs depending on some logic in the controller.  Is there any way to set `tabStyle` dynamically?  I've tried both of the following, and neither one works:

**Attempt #1**

```
<apex:page ... tabStyle="{!IF(some_logic_is_true,'TabA__tab','TabB__tab')}" ... >
```

**Attempt #2**

```
/* in the controller */
public String getTabStyle () {
    if (some_logic_is_true) {
        return 'TabA__tab';
    }
    return 'TabB__tab';
}
```

```
<!-- the VF Page -->
<apex:page ... tabStyle="{!tabStyle}" ... >
```

**Result**: Both of these approaches resulted in the following error:

```
Save error: Invalid tabStyle '{!tabStyle}' specified.  If you are trying to reference
a custom Visualforce tab, you must append '__tab'.
```

Any other ideas out there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to set the tabstyle dynamically. You can vote for the idea [here](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrG5).

You will have to create a separate (empty) visualforce page for each of the tabs that you want to be selected and either include your real page:

```
<apex:page id="thePage" tabstyle="TabA__tab">
    <apex:include pageName="realpage"/>
</apex:page>
```

Or turn your page into a visualforce component and include it that way.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a way of how to customize 'tabStyle' in Page, but you can try to use 'tabStyle' in the apex:pageBlock, see,

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlock.htm

VF page,

```
<apex:page controller="page_tabStyle" showHeader="true" sidebar="false"  >
  <apex:pageBlock title="Hello {!$User.FirstName}!" tabStyle="{!IF($CurrentPage.Parameters.render == 'Account', 'Account', 'Contact')}"  >
        This is your new page for the {!name} controller. <br/>
        You are viewing the {!account.name} account.
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Controller,
`public class page_tabStyle {

public String getName() {
    return 'MyController';
}

public Account getAccount() {
    return [select id, name from Account 
             where id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')]; 
}

}`

When you call like,
https://xxx.c.cs6.visual.force.com/apex/page_tabStyle?id=001N0000003BOTu&render=Account

you got the style of Account,

https://xxx.c.cs6.visual.force.com/apex/page_tabStyle?id=001N0000003BOTu&render=Contact

you got the style of Contact.

Comment: It seems you can't call Controller method directly in tabStyle, so you have to determine how to communicate on the VF page.

Comment: Nice, but per the docs, this only controles "the color scheme of the page block", and the key issue for me is which tab appears to be selected in the tab bar.

Comment: I did a variation of this, I used <....tabStyle="{!IF(strObjNm<>null,strObjNm,'Contact')}">

strObjNm is the API Name of the object that I want to use in the controller. So far it's worked great in my controller